# C structure initialization

Tags: c, structure

I got the following code from internet:

```
struct {
   int x;
   struct {
       int y, z;
   } nested;
} i = { .nested.y = 5, 6, .x = 1, 2 };
```

The result is:

```
i.nested.y = 2
i.nested.z = 6
```

But I don't know why,the article from the net doesn't give any explanation.

Comment: also asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787267/i-dont-understand-this-nested-struct) but not answered:

Comment: `.x = 1, 2` Set to continue

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Mixing designated initializers and non-designated ones is just ... not very clever. In any case, what have you tried? A good starting point would be to look into the C standard and to try to understand the section about initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all let me say that this is a terrible way to initialize a struct, and if it's a homework question - it's not a very good one either.
However, given the problem at hand, what I believe is happening in the initialization is this: first, y is initialized to 5, and z, being the next member in the struct, is initialized to 6. Then, x is initialized to 1 and the next member in the struct, in this case y, is initialized to 2 (which overwrites the 5).

Something important to note as well, is that the nested struct isn't a union, but a struct - first of all, because that's what the code says, but also because if it were a union - it would be impossible in this case for y and z to have different values, since both would be kept in the same location in the memory. : **As answered by Eran Zimmerman on the link provided by Grijesh Chauhan**

Answer (score 4):

Non-designated initializers operate always on the next element in the structure. So the latest `2` operates on what comes after `.x`, which is `.nested.y`. In the same way the `6` goes for the `nested.z`.

If an initializer has several values for an element, the last in the list wins.

But if you have compiler that implements designated initializers, there should be no reason not to use them. The example that you are giving is very much far fetched and not of much educational value.

Comment: See the [CIL output](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/examples/ex34.txt) for this code fragment, Question is from [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/cil016.html) and  [CIL (C Intermediate Language)](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/)

Comment: Indeed, standard says the same. `c11 standard - 6.7.9, 17`

Answer (score 0):

No idea how I mis-read this first, thanks to Jens for pointing this out.

It's simply initializing successive elements "as always", but the designator is used to change the current element first to `.nested.y`, which is initialized to `5` and then the succeeding element `.nested.z` gets the `6`, and so on. The final `2` then overwrites `.nested.y`.

This is rather obfuscated code, since the number of initializers is larger than the number of `int` fields in the struct, something "fishy" (aka "clever") is going on.

Comment: completely off track, there is no comma operator